# MATLAB Common denominator

Tags: matlab, function, symbolic-math

I have this MATLAB function which receives the following input:

```
A=[0 1; 0 -1];
B=[0; 1]
C=[-1 1];
```

Here is the code:

```
function [ T ] = transferMAtrix( A, B, C )
    s=sym('s');
    [n n] = size(A);
    sI=s*sym(eye(n));
    T=sym(C)*inv(sI-sym(A))*sym(B);

end
```

And transferMAtrix(A, B, C) returns the following output:

```
1/(s + 1) - 1/(s*(s + 1))
```

My questions is: is there a method to make those fractions have the same denominator so that the output would be:

```
(s-1)/(s*(s+1))
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>> syms s
>> T=1/(s + 1) - 1/(s*(s + 1))

T =

1/(s + 1) - 1/(s*(s + 1))

>> [n,d]=numden(T)

n =

s - 1


d =

s^2 + s

>> T=n/d

T =

(s - 1)/(s^2 + s)
```

Comment: The fraction is specific to the values of `A`, `B` and `C` in the example, and therefore the result is also specific... I might be wrong here, but I don't think that's what the OP wants.

Comment: Just a note: In recent versions of MATLAB, you can use `simplifyFraction(T)` as well.